# Neovim DAP for typescript says it erros at loadESM

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, neovim

I'm trying to configure DAP for Neovim to debug TS code, but I'm running into an error in the dapui interface:

```
Uncaught Error Error
    at loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:40:33)
    at runMainESM (node:internal/modules/run_main:53:21)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:5)
    at <anonymous> (node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
Process exited with code 1
```

I know the plugin works, becouse running it on pure js works good. Here is some of the .lua file where I config it:

```
local exts = {
  'javascript',
  'typescript',
  'javascriptreact',
  'typescriptreact',
}

for i, ext in ipairs(exts) do
  dap.configurations[ext] = {
      {
          type = 'pwa-node',
          request = 'launch',
          name = 'Launch Current File (pwa-node)',
          cwd = vim.fn.getcwd(),
          args = { '${file}' },
          sourceMaps = true,
          protocol = 'inspector',
      },
     {
      type = 'pwa-node',
      request = 'launch',
      name = 'Launch Current File (pwa-node with ts-node)',
      cwd = vim.fn.getcwd(),
      runtimeArgs = { '--loader', 'ts-node/esm' },
      runtimeExecutable = 'node',
      args = { '${file}' },
      sourceMaps = true,
      protocol = 'inspector',
      skipFiles = { '<node_internals>/**', 'node_modules/**' },
      resolveSourceMapLocations = {
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "!**/node_modules/**",
      },
    },
```

My obv guess is that the *runtimeArgs* setting might not be configured correctly but can't figure what to replace it with.

Answer (score 2):

I've identified the issue, and it turns out it was a mistake on my part.

```
runtimeArgs = { '--loader', 'ts-node/esm' },
      runtimeExecutable = 'node',
```

here *runtimeExecutable* it should be ts-node and withouht the runtimeArgs. Note: I have ts-node installed globally on my machine